# What are ethical rules?

Tags: ethics

Usually people are thinking of ethical rules as "You must [not] X", where X is simple action that does not require any analysis, like "You must not lie".

But if X requires that, is it not a rule anymore? E.g. "You must try for best outcome" is not a rule? What is it then?

*I'm asking this because I can't see the distinction between deontology and consequentialism (assuming "You must try for best outcome" is a rule) or virtue ethics. I'm rather seeing (consequentialism ∪ virtue ethics) ⊂ deontology.*

Comment: See [Deontic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/) as well as [The Logic of Action](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-action/#LogActLin).

Comment: A quick comment here: what you are talking about is "the exception that confirms the rule". Example: "You will be excepted from murder charges if you have willingly killed someone in the special case where it was necessary to protect yourself from being murdered yourself". This **exception** could not exist if there was not a **rule** "Thou shalt do no murder"; there can be no exception if there is no rule to seek exception from. So exceptions can **confirm** a moral rule.

Comment: @MichaelK, but in mathematics exception means that some **rules are incorrect** but other rules can exist that would be correct. Why shouldn't that apply to ethics?

Comment: @rus9384: Rules can be heuristic, ethical, computational,... The rules in mathematics are a very special case of computational/methodological rules.

Comment: @rus9384 Because mathematical rules and moral rules are nothing alike. Mathematical rules prescribe how it **must** be. If we can prove that something violates a mathematical rule, then we have to discard the rule because the rule is wrong. But moral rules are how we **want** things to be, and if someone violates a moral rule, then we say that **they** are wrong and try to correct that behaviour to be aligned with the rule.

Comment: @MichaelK, anyway, is it incorrect to apply rule "One should try to maximize pleasure" in case of hedonism thus making it deontic?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, in terms of computation one might want to define optimal solution. Without it nothing makes sense [nihilism]. Once defined that problem might be decidable or not. If not then no action can lead to best outcome as well as no program (set of rules) exists. If yes, then there definitely exists such program [deontology]. In either way I see no alternatives.

Comment: @rus9384: Several problems with that question: Presupposes moral realism, denies the analysability of "You must not lie", equals moral decision making with computation/logical inference. Life is fuzzy, as natural language is. This needs embedding into a specific framework in order to be answerable.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, it presupposes it only in the case if problem is definable at all. Otherwise we fall into moral skepticism. Also, how one would analyse that question, by what means? Humans only can rely on experience and beliefs and what/who is reliable enough to believe them? Also, if moral decision is impossible for humans, is there even a point in ethics?

Comment: What "lying" or "killing" are requires plenty of analysis, as court cases and ethical debates indicate. Any imperative has descriptive content, indeed is a declarative with "make it (not) happen" attached. The idea that ethics can be mathematized is a fantasy, and if our inability to mathematize something led to nihilism we'd be nihilists about almost everything. Deontic rules have to be definitive enough to be followed in most (not all) practical situations, "optimality" and "best outcome" are too vague for that, they are mostly meta-ethical heuristics to motivate more specific rules.

Comment: I think your argument that deontology can encode consequentialism is sound, but I believe it misses the forest for the trees. Deontology isn't really about the ability to encode arbitrary constraints in rules, it's the normative position that it *makes sense* to talk about and constrain morality in a rule-based manner. If a deontological view of morality isn't solving any problems you have (as it wouldn't if you just redirected to consequentialism), you don't really owe it any credit either.

Comment: @Conifold, does the simplicity of rules make deontology a subcase of moral absolutism? And do consequentialists then think that no short enough (that human can learn and remember when needed) set of simple rules (one might see it as algorithm, although one must define what rules are simple) can solve the problem?

Comment: It depends on what you are willing to call "deontology". So-called [threshold deontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/#WeaDeoThe) discards Kantian absolutism and mandates that rules be followed regardless of consequences only up to a threshold. Mackie's anti-realist error theory also sanctions a form of deontology based on consequentialist meta-ethics because agents routinely lack information, wits, imagination, etc., to make anything like a realistic assessment of consequences, so fixed rules are better suited to produce "best results" on average.

Comment: @Conifold, the latter is closer to what I think, although I also think that virtues as well as rules may be used to guide people in most cases, yet not always. But I think that these concepts altogether (including consequences) are not enough to define morality as they lack intention. And there still are quite many useless (even harmful) rules (and laws) around and thus I'd argue against last statement (although other rules might be better). But consequentialism also can be based on (incorrect wording?) moral absolutism, right?

Answer (score 1):

1 Ethical rules need not be simple. They can be loaded with complexity. All they need is a ground, a moral property, and universality :

For every x, if Gx, then Mx : in every situation in which you are life-threateningly attacked [ground], in that that situation retaliate in self-defence [moral property].

Now that is a simple rule (not one I'm sure I'd accept) but it's clear from the logical form of a rule, just outlined, that the ground could be a monster conjunction and the moral property extremely complex. (I outline a modified logical form in 3 but it does not affect the substance of the argument.)

2 '"You must try for best outcome" is not a rule? What is it then?'

For every x, if Gx, then Mx : For every action, if that action produces the best outcome and is one you can possibly do, then you must try to do that action and hence try for the best outcome.

I'd call that an ethical rule.

3 I have fixed on the type of rule most relevant to your question but it's possible to have a universal rule when, for instance, there are plural and rivalrous values :

For every x, if Gx, then presumptively Mx. The presumption can be defeated if in a particular situation for action Gx grounds, for contextual reasons, a different moral property from M. That is to say, if a different moral property has priority in that specific situation. ('Whenever you make a promise then you should keep it' : in the real complexity of life a presumption is implicit. If the promise is to return a book, but returning the book would prevent you from saving an innocent life, then the presumption that you should keep your promise is defeated by the morally more significant consideration of saving an innocent life. The - to my mind - omnipresence of defeasible presumptions makes ethical rules merely rules of thumb, extremely rough guides, in moral deliberation and action. But that's another story.)